# How to get params from url using Router or ActivatedRoute in angular

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm trying to get parameters from url in AppComponent in my angular application.

But when I use ActivatedRoute to get params it gives null. This is my router configuaration.

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'product/:product',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
```

This is what I tried in AppComponent to get the the result of params from url.

```
constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private router: Router
) {}

ngOnInit() {

this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log(params['product']); //jsut print the result in console
});

//or can use to get the result
//console.log(this.route.snapshot.params['product'];

}
```

this code only works inside particular components. So, Is there any suitable way to get the results.
[Angular 6+]

Comment: where are you subscribing to route.params ? Is it inside any function? please provide complete code

Comment: @SachinGupta yes, I edited the code

Comment: It should work, can you please create a stackblitz to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @SachinGupta This is stackblitz link with the issue: https://angular-9xa95q.stackblitz.io/product/se

Answer (score 0):

First, create a sharedService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  Subject  } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

  myData: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {}

  setData(data) {
    this.myData.next(data);
  }
}
```

Then from where you want to set the data use this method:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.sharedService.setData(data);
    }
}
```

Then in your appComponent:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) {
    this.sharedService.myData.subscribe((value) => {
     console.log(value) // Here you will get your complete data
    });
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Got it now. The issue is because the `AppComponent` is always there and its params are not updated. If you subscribe the `activatedRoute` in `HomeComponent`, you can get the updated value. If the requirement is to get the value in the `AppComponent`, you can follow @Chirag's answer by subscribing in AppCOmponent and updating the value from HomeComponent. 
Check out the forked code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-rg4fj2)